# "next-auth/react" module not found after deploying Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am currently working on a Next.js application and added NextAuth.js for authentication. Everything works locally but when I deploy the project I see an error saying, "Can't resolve 'next-auth/react'. It's specifically flagging the second line on my _app.js. Here is what the code looks like:

```
import "../styles/globals.css"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I've already checked the package.json to make sure I'm using the correct version of NextAuth(^4.0.0-beta.2) and all of the other import statements are correct. I am not deploying the app to Vercel but a private FTP server via DeployHQ.

If there's something I'm missing, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Could you deploy successfully before adding NextAuth authentication?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes I had no issues with deploying before adding NextAuth.